# Is it possible to stealthy boot into a Xen virtual machine? i.e. so no one sees Xen

Tags: xen, hypervisor

Since Xen is a type-1 hypervisor and not a type-2, is it possible to boot into a Xen virtual machine seamlessly as if it there was no hypervisor underneath it? I'm talking about it being such that all the host stuff runs in the background, hidden from the user?

Answer (score 0):

Typically the hypervisor is run on bare-metal hardware for best performance.

Next one or more Guest Virtual Machines (VMs) are run on top of the hypervisor either automatically or manually.  So yes you can setup a guest OS to autorun in seamless window mode (say Windows) and then another guest OS without any UI.  You would need to do work so the user would not see anything unusual during boot but if this is a business perhaps you don't care.

**Summary: Yes** but you probally have much better methods to accomplish your goal.  If we are talking about windows why not just a Windows Service that is seamless and in the background.

Comment: Then how come Xen can chainload PV-GRUB?